# Angular7 slow page load

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular7-router

I have an Angular7 app that was passed onto me. The First Contentful Paint and Time to Interactive is about 6 seconds! It seems to stall(pending) for about 4 seconds on https://www.google-analytics.com/collect and https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans API call, which I found is related with google fonts. But this might not be the cause of the stall. I tried to use lazy loading modules to get bundle smaller. Currently we are at: styles.css 465B, runtime.js 1.1kB, polyfills.js 36kB, styles.js 10kB, vendor.js 583kB, main.js 142kB. Bundle size doesn't seem to be an issue but browser(chrome) still stalls for 6 seconds before user see the home page. Does anyone have any advise?

I also looked at SSR but it seems to be very complicated to setup considering we are serving on AWS S3 using content in dist. I am building with:

```
ng build --outputHashing=all --prod
```

Please help. I am want to make sure there is nothing else I can improve on before trying SSR. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can try and update Angular version to the latest, as it brings performance upgrades and bug fixes. That is what I would do before SSR. Nevertheless, SSR is a "must", if you want better user experience. Considering your bundle size, it is not so big. My app is triple size as yours and it loads faster. As I said, I render on server (SSR) and using v9 so far. But is very hard to answer the question without any code samples.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. Based on https://update.angular.io/, it looks like there are lots of changes from 7.2 to 9.1. For SSR, any suggestions on how to run on AWS? We currently use S3 as web hosting our content in /dist. I've read with Universal, we'll probably need lambda or EC2 to standup a server, e.g. node or heroku.

Comment: Yes, they made some changes from v7 to v9(now v10) regarding performance. I do not have any experience deploying angular app on AWS, but here is the link: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-your-serverless-server-side-rendering-ssr-angular-app-on-aws-lambda-a01a3aab6ef6

Answer (score 1):

You can try to optimize your code a bit and use the `AOT compilation mode` in the time of building.

I found a good article, you can explore this and understand in what way exactly you can improve your code and reduce loading time.
https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angular/tips-to-optimize-your-angular-application

Comment: Thank you. I've read this and it seems --prod would use aot by default in Angular7.